# Larger data rate, Oneweb or Starlink?

Tags: satellite-constellation, starlink, oneweb, internet, bandwidth

Which satellite constellation will provide the larger downlink data rate, in total and per satellite, Oneweb or Starlink?

My consideration: starlink will operate in a lower orbit, with more satellites and a higher throughput per satellite. The reason must be that it is supposed to provide a larger data volume. Am I right? I am doing a journalist research and looking for reliable sources.

Comment: You'll have to make it clearer what "better" means to you; cheaper? faster? lower latency? lower dropouts? direct-to-device versus requires a local earth station? requires a smaller receive antenna for a given S/N ratio? etc. I am not sure either one has an advertised individual end-user (consumer) download speed published yet, these don't really transmit directly into your phone if I understand correctly. So it might be better to ask how these systems are likely to work, and if they require small "ground stations" that act like little servers, rather than direct-to-mobile device.

Comment: ...alternatively the question could be rephrased as a request for outline of the differences between the two systems.

Comment: What are your requirements @Peter? Where would this be used, and for what purpose?

Comment: Even accurately comparing *existing* terrestrial ISPs is challenging, let alone ones that don't really exist yet.

Comment: You could rewrite your question to ask something that's not completely covered in this new article: [SpaceX wants to offer Starlink internet to consumers after just six launches](https://www.teslarati.com/spacex-teases-starlink-internet-service-debut/) also see the new website https://www.starlink.com/